# What are these loops on my backpack for?

Tags: backpacks

On either side of my backpack, I have a loop with some kind of locking mechanism on them. They look like this:

[image: Close up]

They are placed on the upper center of my backpack:

[image: Overview]

The plastic bit at the end can be used to "lock" to itself:

[image: Closed]

What are these loops used for?

The bag itself is a Lowe Alpine Cerro Torre, for reference.

Comment: I can't tell from the photo, but it's possible that these are part of a system for holding an ice ax. However, I can't see any loops at the bottom, which you would need for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are designed to fix your ice axes to the backpack so that they won't move very much. This task should be realized in a lightweight manner and it should be easy and quick to release/adjust. One very common approach is the one from your picture, e.g. explained in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGTtnkXg2fc).

Of course you can adjust e.g. poles with them too. Or anything else if you get the point.

---

**Edit:** Now that I can also see your other pics it really looks like the lower part of the ice axe fixing system is missing. Still the [official notes](https://lowealpine.com/us/cerro-torre-65-85-5) say you can attach ice axes...

You can also check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t66yivA-Hys&feature=youtu.be&t=56), which gives interesting information. I have the pack and already used the fixing system Steve House is representing there.

Comment: They don't look as strong as ice ace loops used to, and I would have thought the lower part would have shown up in the picture but I guess it's just out of shot.

Comment: They should be strong enough because they just adjust the load to the pack. The weight lies on the lower straps (if they are present).

Comment: I'm sure you're right, but without the lower loops we couldn't see they'd be a liability.

Comment: There are indeed no lower identical loop on the backpack. Instead there's [tip grippers](https://lowealpine.com/us/skin/frontend/lowe3/default/images/features/tip-grippers.jpg) (not visible in my photos), which can be used to hold walking poles. I found [this official video](https://vimeo.com/173017795) of them in use in the notes you linked.